# Rails new record with enum is always the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, devise, devise-invitable

I'm using devise invitable to invite new users.

I have a user model with a role column for enum

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [:client, :trainer, :admin]
```

My new user form has the following for the role column

```
.form-group
    = f.label :role, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.select :role, ['client', 'trainer', 'admin'], {},{class: "form-control"}
```

if I choose "client" and submit the form I can see the right parameters are submitted `"role"=>"client"` but when I check the database it always has the role "trainer"

users_controller

```
    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if User.find_by_email(@user.email).nil?
          User.invite!(:email => @user.email)
          redirect_to(users_path, :notice => 'User created')
        else
          render :action => 'new'
        end
      end
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :role, :name)
    end
```

Comment: Do you have role permitted on your user_params?

Comment: @MarceloRisoli yes, of course...

Comment: why is this getting downvoted?

Comment: try `= f.select :role,User.roles.values, {},{class: "form-control"}`

Answer (score -1):

Could this be because you are checking the role at `User.new.role`?
You should check the last created User(`User.last`)